# Importing list of files to compress/zip

Tags: zip, gzip, rar, winzip

Does anybody know of any way (on Windows) to create an archive (zip, rar,..) and adding files to it by importing a list of files to be added (say from a CSV or text file or simply pasted) that need to be archived. Say I have a simple list of 1,000 files across multiple directories that I want to add to an archive, this would be a much simpler method of doing it than adding each file individually.  Also I do not want to arhive the entire directory as it is absolutely massive.

eg: 
c:\somedir\file1.php
c:\somedir\somesubdir\file2.php
c:\someotherdir\file3.php
...

And no I do not want to import all files in certain directories, the hundreds of files are scattered across tens of directories which also contain lots of other files that I do not want to archive.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*rar.exe* from WinRAR has the following option:

```
n@<list>      Include files listed in specified list file
```